# WooCommerce filter all product queries by user selection

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a custom plugin that keeps track of a user's region selection. All my products have four (4) variations, one for each region. The currently selected region is accessible on the front and backend, and that all works fine.

The issue is I don't know how to filter all product queries by their selected region. If a product doesn't have a variation with a matching region, the product should be filtered out.
If the matching variation exists but is out of stock, the product should be filtered out.

Under products->attributes->region, there are 4 region slugs, and I've tried different combinations of hooks and actions without success.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec There's no dropdown, this is to filter out all products that don't have a matching region variation. Seems like you're referring to seeing/hiding variations on single product pages. The goal is to hide the parent completely (from searches and categories) if no children have the matching region or aren't in stock. This might still come in handy when I want to add conditional stuff to the single pages later.

Your second comment seems like it covers the use case. I'll update my post with code if I have troubles in the implementation. Thank you

Comment: I just listed the right things (all of them). To hide the parent product of course use: `woocommerce_is_purchasable`, `woocommerce_product_query`,`,woocommerce_product_query_tax_query`... As your question is poorly documented and detailed, without any related code, there is very poor chances that you will get something really helpful.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Might be a bit unorthodox, but what do you think about: adding handlers for when a child is edited or stocks change so that it sets an attribute on the parent. Then I can have a low cost query on only the parent to filter out products that don't have the attribute that says the child is available. Can't tell from the outset all the implications of this, but please let me know. This seems like a less intensive way to handle it.

Comment: Yes of course it's an excellent idea to add metadata on the patent product !

Comment: Also I know, there's always something wrong with the question. However, I don't see how I could put forward code for hooks/actions I don't even know about at the time of posting, and ways to do something I also don't know about. Without a plan, I can make up some random and unrelated code for people to check off the "has code" box but I don't see how it would help.